# Verifying ETH Deposit Contract signatures using Chainsafe BLS library

Tags: web3js, nodejs, encryption, eth-2.0

I am attempting to verify BLS signatures using the [Chainsafe BLS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chainsafe/bls). I am attempting to independently verify signatures associated with deposits to the [ETH Deposit Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa). In order to test that I am using the library correctly, I used the `verify` function on the [following deposit](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb0895a99dd10618cd8026b2e15d6113fa8445ae005bb3d311d3721d175317aa4#eventlog).

When I attempted to verify the deposit, the function returned false.

I made a couple of assumptions which may have led to this error.

1. I inputed all arguments as strings.
2. For the `message` parameter, I inserted the users withdrawal credentials

This is what my function looked like:

```
bls.verify('8B0F65FDDD2F4A5228114BCFB7594806BD7B1A0D08C6EC4D4E050EBEE56B9EAD36A65B8581D23EE142E81499A0CE2193',
'00A96066AC9AB401F87AD05E2ED4E6DF5AE2658E532BF2753DB8A0907EFF72A8', 
'92507CDF84A2EFDF41202492A227684DB679CE8F811C313747CD3B25CB6701D50E2A32327CF374DB82862EC482BDA7D30CF8C0823617C2252E6CB8C771EF358FDF092B30CBE2249B8D752F9521BA7653FB198C8B692734C331E21887977186F0')
```

How did I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the canonical definition of the deposit signature in [ethereum/eth2.0-specs: `process_deposit`](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v1.0.0/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#deposits). Specifically, it is this code:

```py
# Verify the deposit signature (proof of possession) which is not checked by the deposit contract
deposit_message = DepositMessage(
    pubkey=deposit.data.pubkey,
    withdrawal_credentials=deposit.data.withdrawal_credentials,
    amount=deposit.data.amount,
)
domain = compute_domain(DOMAIN_DEPOSIT)  # Fork-agnostic domain since deposits are valid across forks
signing_root = compute_signing_root(deposit_message, domain)
if not bls.Verify(pubkey, signing_root, deposit.data.signature):
    return
```

The `message` isn't just the `withdrawal_credentials`, it's the `signing_root` (a.k.a. merkle root) of a `DepositMessage` obect. Due to the complexity involved I won't go into detail to describe the entire process but the specs (linked above) should be comprehensive enough to describe the process exactly.